# Get the iframe id content was loaded into from the loaded javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm going to try and keep this as simple as possible.

I have two html files, `a.html` and `b.html`.
Within `a.html` there is an iframe tag with an id.
`b.html` gets loaded into the iframe in `a.html`.
`b.html` also has a javascript file being loaded.

Is there any way to get the id of the iframe `b.html` was loaded into from the `b.js` file?

Comment: If both pages are from the same domain and `b.html` is only loaded into _one_ specific iframe … then you could simply loop over the iframe elements of the parent document and see which one’s `src` points to `b.html` …

Comment: You need to provide it via javascript and iframe message passing to the b.html's javascript, where you can listen for the message. It's the only way.